# Qt 5.5 and OpenGL: Retrieving device info

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I've written a Qt 5.5 application that uses OpenGL in the form of a QOpenGLWidget. Now I'd like it so that the user can see their device info from the application. By this I mean something along the lines of:

- The card's name, e.g. "GT 640"
- Vendor
- Total GPU memory
- Driver version
- An extension list

So far, I myself have been unable to find any relating functions. Although I am aware that this can be done by making calls to OpenGL, I'd much rather keep all the code relatively high-level. I found [this](http://www.qtforum.org/article/598/getting-information-about-graphics-cards-with-qt.html) very old post from 2004 stating that Qt does not have this feature, but maybe times have changed?

Comment: Total GPU Memory and Driver Version are rough, but the other three things are easy to get. I've wrapped my work around proprietary APIs for AMD, NV and Intel to get the first two things mentioned and you're probably going to have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Card name: no cross-platform way of getting it. It *may* be returned as part of `glGetString(GL_RENDERER)`, for instance on NVIDIA I get

  > GeForce GTX 980 PCIe/SSE2
- Vendor: `glGetString(GL_VENDOR)`

  > NVIDIA Corporation
- Total GPU memory: absolutely not cross platform. Use [`GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info.txt) for NVIDIA, `AMD_gpu_association` (platform dependent) or [`GL_ATI_meminfo`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ATI/meminfo.txt) for AMD/ATI. Note that knowing the amount of VRAM is almost useless, you have several sublimits for any particular object you will try to create (maximum VBO size, maximum texture size, texture level size, renderbuffer size...).
- Driver version: absolutely not cross platform, *may* be included as part of `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` (which allows for vendor-specific info at the end), otherwise you'll need once more to go platform-specific:

  > 4.5.0 NVIDIA 346.87
- Extensions list: with Qt, `QOpenGLContext::extensions()`, `hasExtension()`, plus the resolved function pointer helpers (`getProcAddress()`, `QOpenGLFunctions`, `QOpenGLVersionFunctions`, etc.). Any other GL resolver (e.g. GLEW) has equivalent methods. And you *want* to use resolvers and not go down to the platform specific again...

Comment: I've tried it on my PC Ubuntu18.04, Qt5.13. The outputs of the above lines are like:
0x6ffffd2c31bc0, etc. They seem like the address of the graphic card. Could you explain more about the lines?