# How to get GPU memory type from WMI

Tags: c++, qt, gpu, windows

I want to detect GPU memory type (for-example GDDR5) using WMI. 
[image]

How to get such information? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For nvidia cards you can use [GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info.txt), there's no multiplatform way to do this. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386770/qt-5-5-and-opengl-retrieving-device-info).

Comment: I need only for Windows. What about WMI? Or there are no such property?

Comment: This function works on _any_ system that supports OpenGL, problem is that it can read info only about NV cards.

WMI seems to be some Windows–related thing, I'm 'that Linux guy', so…

Comment: Thanks. But I use WMI to get some data from GPU, so I need to find solution using WMI if this possible.